# django: Unexpected data type exception trying to use django-excel

Tags: python, django, excel

So I am trying to use django-excel: https://github.com/pyexcel/django-excel
and just simply export a certain model into xls. I set up the settings according to the documentation, but I got this error when running:

```
Exception at /calbase/export/sheet
Unexpected data type <class 'django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile'>
```

Here is my views:

```
def export_data(request, atype):
    if atype == "sheet":
        return excel.make_response_from_a_table(
            Equipment, 'xls', file_name="sheet")
    elif atype == "book":
        return excel.make_response_from_tables(
            [Equipment, Calibration], 'xls', file_name="book")
    elif atype == "custom":
        equipment = Equipment.objects.get(slug='ide')
        query_sets = Choice.objects.filter(equipment=equipment)
        column_names = ['choice_text', 'id', 'votes']
        return excel.make_response_from_query_sets(
            query_sets,
            column_names,
            'xls',
            file_name="custom"
        )
    else:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest(
            "Bad request. please put one of these " +
            "in your url suffix: sheet, book or custom")
```

and when I tried to go

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/calbase/export/sheet

it gives me the exception above.

By the way is there any good example using django-excel? I can't seem to run the one provided

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/calbase/export/sheet

Django Version: 1.10
Python Version: 3.5.2
Installed Applications:
['calbase.apps.CalbaseConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'haystack',
 'whoosh',
 'carton']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\hansong.li\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\hansong.li\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\hansong.li\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\hansong.li\Documents\GitHub\equipCal\calbase\views.py" in export_data
  97.             Equipment, 'xls', file_name="sheet")

File "C:\Users\hansong.li\Documents\GitHub\equipCal\django_excel\__init__.py" in make_response_from_a_table
  147.                          file_name=file_name, **keywords)

File "C:\Users\hansong.li\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pyexcel_webio\__init__.py" in make_response
  244.     file_stream = pyexcel_instance.save_to_memory(file_type, None, **keywords)

File "C:\Users\hansong.li\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pyexcel\sheets\sheet.py" in save_to_memory
  114.         self.save_to(out_source)

File "C:\Users\hansong.li\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pyexcel\sheets\sheet.py" in save_to
  79.         source.write_data(self)

File "C:\Users\hansong.li\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pyexcel\sources\file_source_output.py" in write_data
  86.                                              sheet, **self.keywords)

File "C:\Users\hansong.li\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pyexcel\sources\renderer\_excel.py" in render_sheet_to_stream
  35.                   **keywords)

File "C:\Users\hansong.li\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pyexcel_io\io.py" in save_data
  70.                **keywords)

File "C:\Users\hansong.li\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pyexcel_io\io.py" in store_data
  91.     writer.write(data)

File "C:\Users\hansong.li\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pyexcel_io\book.py" in write
  177.                 sheet_writer.write_array(incoming_dict[sheet_name])

File "C:\Users\hansong.li\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pyexcel_io\sheet.py" in write_array
  82.             self.write_row(row)

File "C:\Users\hansong.li\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pyexcel_xls\xls.py" in write_row
  230.                 self.native_sheet.write(self.current_row, i, value)

File "C:\Users\hansong.li\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Worksheet.py" in write
  1033.         self.row(r).write(c, label, style)

File "C:\Users\hansong.li\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Row.py" in write
  263.             raise Exception("Unexpected data type %r" % type(label))

Exception Type: Exception at /calbase/export/sheet
Exception Value: Unexpected data type <class 'django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile'>
```

Comment: The reason is xlwt could not write django's FieldFile. xlwt only support a few primitives. The work around is to obtain the sheet first, and filter out FieldFile column(or transform it into a recognized type, e.g. string), and make_response() from your sheet instance. A bit further, django-excel could have supported "column_names" field so as to exclude the field.

Comment: @chfw that was the problem. Thanks

Comment: @HansongLi did you resolve the problem?